# php: curl script working but not in php file

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl script that is working fine in terminal.

```
curl -XPOST \
     -F "file=@var/www/myfile.wav;type=audio/wav" \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer $MY_TOKEN' \
     'https://myurl'
```

I have tried this way in my php file,

```
<?php

    $url = "https://myurl";
    $key =  "myKey";

    $path = "/var/www/";
    $fileName = "myfile.wav";
    $data['file']=  "@".$path.$fileName;
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Authorization: Bearer $key"));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $response;

?>
```

I get an error from the server. Seems I am not making request as the server expects. Am I missing anything in the php script?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

$data = array('file' =>  file_get_contents($path.$fileName));

There may be a problem with your CURL library that PHP is using.

Or PHP may be blocked from making HTTPS connections.

Try a series of simple tests using CURL in PHP like this first one with POST false:

```
<?php 

    $url = "https://myurl/";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    echo $response;
?>
```

and then with POST true...

```
<?php 

    $url = "https://myurl/";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: @Rifat it's also possible there is a bug in the curl library.  There doesn't seem to be any difference in the terminal, and the PHP script.

Comment: The server just returns error occurred. if I do an exec on my script its getting executed but no luck with the php script !

Comment: @Rifat If your question included the values for your url and key/token then I could use a HTTP debugger to find out what's different.  Otherwise, I'd recommend using Charles (on Mac) or Fiddler (on windows)

Comment: @Rifat I was able to upload to my own server using exactly the same code you posted that you say doesn't work. So I know it does work, customized for my server :)

Comment: I am using the exec command for the time being. No idea what to do instead!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an HTTPs URL , You need to make use of this parameter

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: What error do you get ? `doesn't work` really won't help anyone answer your question. Could you elaborate the error ?

Comment: The server is just returning "en error occurred". its a third party service I am using. But the server returns correctly when I run the curl script.